# Efficiently append CSV files python

Tags: python, csv, append

I am trying to append > 1000 csv files (all with the same format) in Python. The files have anything between 1KB and 30GB. All the files have 200GB in total. I want to combine these files into a unique dataframe. Below what I am doing which is very very slow:

```
folder_path = 'Some path here'
csv_files = [file for file in os.listdir(folder_path) if file.endswith('.csv')]
combined_data = pd.DataFrame()
for e, csv_file in enumerate(csv_files): 
    print(f'Processing {e+1} out of {len(csv_files)}: {csv_file}')
    combined_data = pd.concat([combined_data, pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_path, csv_file), dtype={'stringbvariablename': str})])
```

One of the variables is a string. Everything else numbers. RAM memory is not an issue since I am using a cluster.

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question: what you want is to combine all the data in multiple csv's into a single dataframe, NOT (I hope) merging everything into a single CSV file. You should also explain the intent here, as operating with multiple dataframes may or may not be more efficient for concurrency/parallelism reasons.

Comment: So you basically want to concatenate the files into a single file? Have all files the same structure (same columns in the same order)?

Comment: Of course this is slow, `pd.concat(` in a loop is a classic anti-pattern. What is it you are actually trying to accomplish, creating a new CSV file? If you actually need the dataframe, then append individual dataframes to a list, then `pd.concat` that list at the end. Otherwise, if you are just trying to create a new csv, you probably shouldn't even use pandas

Comment: "RAM memory is not an issue since I am using a cluster."??? the code you've shown would not leverage a cluster. It would be limited by the memory of a single node.

Comment: @MichaelButscher that is correct.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, what I meant is that I can allocate 300GB of memory to a single node.

Comment: @justlearning, all my CSVs have the same columns. I just want to put all the data into one big dataframe, yes.

Comment: @phdstudent do you want a *dataframe* or do you want to create a new csv file?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga a dataframe that I can then manipulate. Sorry I mispoke earlier. But if the faster is to create a new CSV combined and then load, then that's fine as well.

Comment: @phdstudent look at my answer, I have both for you

Comment: Anyway, you may not actually have enough memory. 300gb is probably not enough, if I were to guesstimate, but it depends on your data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of your files are in the same format, and you are just trying to create a new CSV, then ditch pandas.

```py
import csv
import pathlib


def write_to_writer(writer: csv.writer, path: pathlib.Path, skipheader=False) -> None:
    with path.open(newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        if skipheader:
            next(reader)
        writer.writerows(reader)

folder_path = pathlib.Path('Some path here')
csv_files = [p for p in folder_path.iterdir() if p.suffix =='.csv']


with open('combined_data.csv', 'w', newline="") as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    # handle first csv, with header
    first_path, *rest = csv_paths
    write_to_writer(writer, first_path, skipheader=False)
    for path in rest:
        write_to_writer(writer, path, skipheader=True)
```

This avoids the `pd.concat` in a loop problem, which is a [classic antipattern](https://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter).

However, if you need a large dataframe (because you are going to actually use the dataframe), then your problem is fixed simply by appending to a list and then concating at the end:

```py
import pathlib

import pandas as pd

folder_path = pathlib.Path('Some path here')
csv_paths = [p for p in folder_path.iterdir() if p.suffix =='.csv']


df = pd.concat([
    pd.read_csv(path, dtype={'stringbvariablename': str})
    for path in csv_paths
])
```

Again, this avoids the anti-pattern (because `.append`ing to a list in a loop *is efficient*)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this, and will accept the answer once I have tried it.

Comment: anyway it can print to screen how far ahead on the concatenation process it is?

Comment: @phdstudent you could use the `tqdm` library, and then it becomes `for path in tqdm.tqdm(csv_paths)` and that will give you a progress bar. Note, if it is still very slow you may just be running into memory limitations. You are going to need *double* the memory you expect the final dataframe to occupy (and note, because something takes 200gb in a csv file, it may require much more (or much less) to represent that in-memory, it all depends on the specifics of your data)

Answer (score -1):

Give [***joinem***](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem) a try, available via PyPi: `python3 -m pip install joinem`.

*joinem* provides a CLI for fast, flexbile concatenation of tabular data using [polars](https://pola.rs).
I/O is *lazily streamed* in order to give good performance when **working with numerous, large files**.

### Example Usage

Pass input files via stdin and output file as an argument.

```bash
ls -1 path/to/*.csv | python3 -m joinem out.csv
```

You can add the `--progress` flag to get a progress bar.

### Further Information

*joinem* is also compatible with parquet, JSON, and feather file types.
See the project's [README](https://github.com/mmore500/joinem/) for more usage examples and a full command-line interface API listing.

*disclosure*: I am the library author of *joinem*.